# How to save multiple outputs after reading multiple inputs in Python

Tags: python, image, opencv

i am reading .png images from a folder and doing some operations and i want to save those images in an order like Img1.png, Img2.png, Img3.png.... i tried to use this code :

```
cv2.imwrite("Img{}.png".format(i),Image)
```

but it keeps overriding single image.

below is the code:

```
def main(path):
    i=0
    image = cv2.imread(path)

    #do some operations on image

    cv2.imwrite('Img{}.png'.format(i),image)
    i=i+1
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The path contains multiple .png images so when main executes it resets the value of 'i' and output is overridden.

Comment: I don't know the complexity of your program but can't you use a global variable for i ?

Comment: what module do You use?

Comment: i tried to use the global variable but it shows an error.

i use numpy and opencv and python version 2.7.14

Comment: It sounds like you want to figure out which images are already in the directory, and then just start your index at the next available image name.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's because of the type of formatting. The old python uses `'%s %s' % ('one', 'two')`format, did you try this formatting?

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that path - space separated:

```
path = "im1.png  imre.png  lena.jpg"
```

it seams so:

```
path_lst = path.split(' ')
for i, path_i in enumerate(path_lst):
    image = cv2.imread(path_i)
    #do some operations on image
    cv2.imwrite('Img{}.png'.format(i),image)
```

all works. Idk - why they gave me "-" =D